# Blank desktop after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation

I performed a clean install from an Ubuntu 14.04 iso disk. When I login I get a blank desktop with only the Ubuntu 14.04 logo showing in the lower left-hand corner of the screen. Nothing comes up on the screen when I right-click my mouse. I have to power off my HP PC in order to try to reboot the computer.

I have tried numerous suggestions from other threads with the same issue. I am fairly new to Ubuntu and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your DE/WM didn't get load properly, or is hung creating your initial homedir profile settings. You may want to try creating another user, and logging in with it to see if that works. You can do so from the command line (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) with the adduser command.

Also, check the X log to see if there is any indications at the bottom:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem 2 months ago, after a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 I get a blank desktop, I fixed reinstalling the O.S.

I know that is not the best answer, but it works for me.

Thanks